# How to parse ?var1=something in urls.py?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have to handle type of link like this:

```
http://mydomain/?var1=something&var2=something
```

How to redirect this to a standard django view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GET parameters aren't passed to urls.py
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/). 
When you are in view use request.GET to capture this parameters.

Answer (score 0):

GET parameters is parsed automatically. So, in urls.py you should write url without these parameters, e.g. `"^$"` (empty url) in your case. Or, for example, for url `http://mydomain/some/path?var1=something&var2=something` you need to write `"^some/path$"` in urls.py. Then in your view you will have `request.GET["var1"]` and  `request.GET["var2"]` if they were passed.

Comment: I now, but old site have these links and new site needs to handle this.